# How to select unique discounts in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables. I want to find the unique discount values of all 5 tables using MYSQL.

The form of the tables is:

```
table1(userid,discount)  
table2(userid,discount)    
table3(userid,discount)    
table4(userid,discount)    
table5(userid,discount)
```

Comment: you should be able to join the tables together. can you post some sample data? doing a bunch of selects in a union is not that great of a solution.. if you post some data I can give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION` to achieve this.

The default behavior for `UNION` is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional `DISTINCT` keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal.

With the optional `ALL` keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the `SELECT` statements.

**Query**

```
select discount from table1
union
select discount from table2
union
select discount from table3
union
select discount from table4
union
select discount from table5;
```

And if you want to sort the result from above sql query, you can use an `ORDER BY` like below.

**Query**

```
select t.discount from
(
    select discount from table1
    union
    select discount from table2
    union
    select discount from table3
    union
    select discount from table4
    union
    select discount from table5
)t
order by t.discount;
```

order by descending or ascending as per your requirement.

Comment: Hooray!  An answer that gets straight to the point that UNION means UNION DISTINCT (as opposed to UNION ALL).

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL `union`

```
select * from (
    select * from table1
    union
    select * from table2
    union
    select * from table3
    union
    select * from table4
    union
    select * from table5
)new group by new.discount
```

Comment: I want to get the distinct results

Comment: Then better use distinct

Answer (score 0):

Combine distinct and union

```
Select distinct discount from
(SELECT discount from table1
Union
Select discount from table2
Union
Select discount from table3
Union
Select discount from table4
Union
Select discount from table5) As tview
```

Comment: You have used the distinct keyword twice in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
select distinct discount from (
select userid,discount from table1
union 
select userid,discount from table2
union 
select userid,discount from table3
union 
select userid,discount from table4
union 
select userid,discount from table4)a
```